# How to go to a selected date in Material Calendar View?

Tags: android, calendarview

I'm using [material-calendarview](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) in my project. I can change the selection of the date using setSelectedDate() method. I've a button as "Today selection".My intention is to move the views to current date by clicking this button.There are methods goToNext() and goToPrevious() which only changes one month.But if it is two or more month forward or backward,then how should i change the view to selected date or current date.I tried using invalidate() but nothing happens.

Answer (score 6):

For those people who are having a hard time on this one, 
update your gradle to :

```
compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.2'
```

there is a function :

`calendarView.setCurrentDate(CalendarDay.from(year, month, day), true);`

no more computation, pager directs to selected date. kudos.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar to @Patriotic but was able to do it off current state of calendar rather than a listener and counter.

```
private void selectDate(Date date) {
    Calendar startCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    startCalendar.setTime(date);
    Calendar endCalendar = calendarView.getCurrentDate().getCalendar();

    calendarView.setSelectedDate(date);

    int diffYear = endCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int diffMonth = diffYear * 12 + endCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int monthsToMove = Math.abs(diffMonth);
    for (int i = 0; i < monthsToMove; i++) {
        if (diffMonth < 0) {
            calendarView.goToNext();
        } else if (diffMonth > 0) {
            calendarView.goToPrevious();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```kotlin
//this is default
calendarMonth.currentDate = CalendarDay.today()

//ok?
calendarMonth.selectedDate = CalendarDay.today()
```

Comment: Please add some proper explanation to your answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, here are some guidelines : **it is not recommended** to post code-only answers, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make it the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

I've handled this issue somehow so, i thought i should share it with community.

- Global counter variable to keep track of month.

  `private int counter;`
- setOnMonthChangedListener() to listen the month
- Compare date with current date.

  ```
  final Calendar currentCal=Calendar.getInstance();
  currentCal.set(Calendar.DATE,1);

  calendarView.setOnMonthChangedListener(new OnMonthChangedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onMonthChanged(MaterialCalendarView widget, CalendarDay date) {
          if(date.getYear()==currentCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
              if(date.getMonth()<currentCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)){
                  --counter;
              }else if(date.getMonth()>currentCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)){
                  ++counter;
              }
          }else if(date.getYear()<currentCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
              --counter;
          }else if(date.getYear()>currentCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
              ++counter;
          }
      }
  });
  ```
- When Button triggered, checked the counter and changed the view to current date using goToNext() and goToPrevious() method.

  ```
  int c=Math.abs(counter);
  for (int i = 0; i <c ; i++) {
      if(counter<0){
          calendarView.goToNext();
      }else if(counter>0){
          calendarView.goToPrevious();
      }
  }
  ```

  counter=0;

Comment: any fix on this ?

Comment: What kind of fix you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

First find material calendar view after using this:

```
calendarView = (MaterialCalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
calendarView.setSelectionMode(MaterialCalendarView.SELECTION_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: MY post is At a time select multiple dates in calendar.

Comment: yes i can see your post but you need to format your code

Answer (score 0):

All answers not do what is needed 
the solution is:

```
 val current = calendar.time
    calendarMaterial!!.selectionMode = SELECTION_MODE_RANGE
    calendarMaterial!!.setCurrentDate(CalendarDay.from(current),true)
    calendarMaterial!!.state().edit()
                .setMinimumDate(current)
                .commit()
```

this will prevent old date from selection but currently it sits it to unvisible .. i am working on just set it to gray