# How to get previous and next month clickListener in MaterialCalanderView

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am using materialcalanderview to display calander. On click of previous and next month buttons (Swipe buttons) I have to do some operations. How can I get the clicklistener for these swipe buttons

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456628/how-to-go-to-a-selected-date-in-material-calendar-view

Comment: Yes, But how can I get the swipe listeners and month back and next listeners, I have to highlight specific dates for that perticular month on swipe or whenever user changes the month in calander

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution.
MonthChangeListener you can use. Putting a code snippet below

```
calendar.setOnMonthChangedListener(new OnMonthChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMonthChanged(MaterialCalendarView widget, CalendarDay date) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Month Changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```